# Register using Facebook and create user profile in Django-Rest

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using `django-allauth` and `dj-rest-auth` in my django-rest project to register users and allow them to sign in to my react-native app. The problem I am having is that when the user is registered, it creates the particular user in a `social accounts` table. However, I want to also create a `user profile` for each member who registers via Facebook and store additional data (name, email, picture). I have had a look at docs, blogs, stack-overflow but just can't seem to figure out how I can do this.

So far, I have a `social_login` app which manages the login and has a view which has the following:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

How can I edit the `social accounts` model? and how can I create a user profile in my `users` app once a user has registered using Facebook?

### Update:

I have realised that I can only have one user auth table in Django which manages user, regardless of whether they are customers or staff. I have now migrated to using a custom user model using the `AbstractUser` from Django. I could potentially create another table for user profiles which could then hold additional details or extend the model I have now. I will extend the `User` model I have created as I think created an extra model would be overkill for my current needs.

[This](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/) blog post helped me migrate to using a custom user model mid-project.

I also realised that I am able to make use of [`allauth` signals](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) (`user_signed_up` in particular for my case) in order to trigger a function. I'm fairly new to Python/Django so didn't even know what a signal was till about 30 mins ago. It's fair to say you learn something new everyday :)

Comment: hi, can you provide some information on how you make it work I am getting `{"non_field_errors":["Incorrect value"]}` on my view its same as yours.